# Logical statement/puzzle. How to only pick the price with a loyalty_card and leave out other prices?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've been trying to figure this out for some time but I'm out of ideas.

**Context**

I'm trying to calculate the total_room_price when a person rents a room for a couple of nights. The room_prices are unique for dates, **unless a specific room_price is set with a loyalty_card.**

In the later scenario, it's possible that a date has 2 different prices:

1. room_price without a loyalty card
2. room_price with a loyalty
   card

In the case a reservation includes a loyalty_card, the reservation should only include the room_price with a loyalty card.

**Issue**

My current set-up works for a user without a loyalty_card.

However, for users with a loyalty card (where the reservation.loyalty_card matches the loyalty_card of the room_price), the method adds up both prices for a date, room_price with a loyalty card and room price without a loyalty card.

How can I just use the room_price with loyalty_card in such a scenario?

```
  def total_room_price(reservation)
    sum_room = 0
    price_list = []
      (reservation.arrival...reservation.departure).each do |date|
        reservation.room.room_category.room_prices.each do |price|
          if ((price.start_date..price.end_date).include? date) && (price.loyalty_card.nil? || price.loyalty_card == reservation.loyalty_card)
            sum_room += price.price
          end
        end
      end
    sum_room
  end
```

models

```
class RoomPrice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :room_category
  belongs_to :card, optional: true
end

class Card < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :hotel
  has_many :discounts
  has_many :room_prices
  has_many :reservations
end

class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :discount, optional: true
  belongs_to :card, optional: true
  belongs_to :hotel
  belongs_to :room
end
```

Comment: Just use an if-else statement to check for price.loyalty_card.blank? and do your calculations as needed.  You're 95% of the way there.

Comment: @bkunzi01 Thanks for your response. How would you use this if-else statement. The problem I'm seeing is that when I'm iterating over the date>price I'm not sure if there is another price for the same date, but with a card included.

Comment: Post your relevant models and their attributes. Where are the prices for the rooms coming from? Are they calculated on the fly or taken through an API etc?  How are the loyalty discounts calculated? It may help you to draw out the expected logic in a flow diagram and then code it. I.E. Get room and dates, get price (or are you calculating price?), check if room has loyalty discount &&  loyalty card supplied else use initial price. Etc.

Comment: You're completely right, I added the models. The room_price are specified in my program via a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by using a 2-step approach, but it's really comprehensive. If someone has a better solution, I'm all ears.

```
def total_room_price(reservation)
    sum_room = 0
    dates = reservation.arrival...reservation.departure
      dates.each do |date|
        #arrangement card
        reservation.room.room_category.room_prices.each do |price|
          if ((price.start_date...price.end_date).include? date) && (price.card == reservation.card)
            sum_room += price.price
            dates = dates.without(date)
          end
        end
      end

        #arrangement no card
        dates.each do |arr_no_card_date|
          reservation.room.room_category.room_prices.each do |arr_price|
            if ((arr_price.start_date...arr_price.end_date).include? arr_no_card_date) && (arr_price.card.nil?)
              sum_room += arr_price.price
              dates = dates.without(arr_no_card_date)
            end
          end
        end
     sum_room
  end
```